# Connect to Bluetooth tethering

Tags: ipad, tethering

I have my Android phone set up with Bluetooth tethering and it's sharing its WiFi connection. I use this WiFi connection on my iPad (iOS 10.1.1). I have paired the devices via Bluetooth and switched off WiFi on the iPad, but I don't see any option to use WiFi via Bluetooth? How do I set this up on the iPad?

Excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: I dont understand the question exactly. You have 1 android phone and 1 iPad and you want to connect to WiFi with the Ipad, from a hotspot put out by the phone?

Comment: @petergus Exactly. I want to use the WiFi from the phone with the iPad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your android phone should make a WiFi hotspot when enabled, which acts like any other normal wifi hotspot as far as the iPad is concerned (connect via WIFI settings). It doesn't operate over Bluetooth at all, neither on the phone nor on the iPad.